# Using Stata to graph dates

Tags: stata

I'm trying to graph the CPI over the years. Therefore, I want to make the x-axis as the dates and the y-axis as the numerical values. I got the data in .csv file and the dates are in the format yyyy-mm-dd. However, whenever I use

```
graph twoway scatter date value
```

Stata returns: "varlist:  date:  string variable not allowed". How can I format the dates into such a way that Stata can read? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try `help datetime` to see how to convert string dates to Stata dates (integers that represent days since Jan 1, 1960 with nice labels). You most likely need something like:

```
gen stata_date = date(csv_date,"YMD")
format stata_date %td
```

or

```
format stata_date %tdCCYY/MM/DD
```

to use the same formatting as before.

There's also a `twoway tsline` command that works nicely with dates once you `tsset` your data as a time series.

Finally, you have x and y reversed.

BTW, you can get a lot of data from user-written `quandl`, `freduse`, or `wbopendata`. Here's the time-series for the CPI for All Urban Consumers (excluding farmers, soldiers, criminals who got caught, and really crazy people):

```
capture ssc install quandl 
quandl, q(FRED/CPIAUCSL) clear 
tw tsline value
```

This has the advantage of doing the formatting/tssetting for you.

Comment: This helpful answer underlines by example that to Stata "date format" means only whatever date format is assigned by a `format` command. A string looking like a date is just that, a string looking like a date. Date-time variables must be numeric variables.

Answer (score 0):

After formatting the date, you can also use `xtline` command to plot.

```
xtline GDP, i(country_id) t(time_variable)
```